# Сборка Qt5 проекта

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Дано задание написать приложение в Qt5 и сказано, что в скрипте Cmake необходимо предусмотреть инсталляцию скомпилированного приложения в систему Linux. Долго гуглил как на русском, так и на английском и по итогу ничего не нашел. Благодарю!

Comment: https://www.qt.io/blog/cmake-deployment-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.qt.io/blog/deploying-to-linux-with-cmake

**-- Set runtime path of "/tmp/my-application/bin/myapp" to "$ORIGIN:$ORIGIN/../lib"** - в консоли после ввода для сборки, такое появляется, значит уже на линукс собирается.

*Есть короче казус, если в проге подключен класс, который с файлами работает QFile или QProcess или QDataStream с выводом в файл, то вручную в коде прописывай 2 разных директории.*